# $(document).on('click' not working properly

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('click', '.delete', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id'); // row ID 
          alert(id);
          var i = confirm("Want to Delete this");
          if (i === true) {

              $("#" + id).remove();
          }
      });
  });
```

This code is not working properly on clicking any element on row it is removing content and not asking `Want to delete this`
Code should only activate on click `.delete`

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RHKhw/

How to correct it.

Comment: confirmation popup "pops" perfectly  in your fiddle (chrome).

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson What difference would that make?

Comment: Fiddle pops the question when I click the image

Comment: On clicking any element on row it is removing entore `.row`

Comment: It's not being removed by the above code. Something in boostrap.js is removing the entire `div.panel-body`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete only when the image is clicked:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.delete').on('click',function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var id = $(this).closest('.row').attr('id'); // row ID 
          alert(id);
          var i = confirm("Want to Delete this");
          if (i === true) {
              $("#" + id).remove();
          }
      });
  });
```

Also need to remove `data-dismiss="alert"`: http://jsfiddle.net/RHKhw/12/

Comment: remove `data-dismiss="alert"`

Comment: Use the above code and delete ' data-dismiss="alert" ' and it should work.  http://jsfiddle.net/RHKhw/9/ Check it

Answer (score 2):

The `data-dismiss` property on your row is causing you issues. This will dismiss the contents of your row after an alert (built-in bootstrap functionality). Just remove that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHKhw/8/)**

The problem is here,

```
<div class="row" data-dismiss="alert" id="r1">
                     ^
```

Remove the property. It removes the row content.